# Unexpected behavior of printf() in C

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int a = 5;
    printf("%d" + 1, a);
    return 0;
}
```

The code prints the alphabet enclosed in quotes in `printf` irrespective of the value and type of variable `a`. If any other number is added except 1 nothing gets printed.
Why is it so?

Comment: Ignore `printf`.  What does `"string" + 1` mean?

Comment: What exactly do you expect this to print out?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, I would expect it to print just `d`, of course. That's what happened when I tested it.

If you add more than 1 (or 2) all bets are off and you're getting undefined behavior for passing a random pointer instead of a valid formatting string.

Comment: Why should it print d in the first place?

Comment: @user3202188 Because the format string you're passing starts one character beyond the start of the string `"%d"`, which is the string `"d"`. Basic pointer arithmetic.

Comment: When you ADD a NUMBER to a STRING, you get a new string which starts that number of characters past the beginning of the original string.  This is a specific example of the more general C principle of "pointer arithmetic."

Answer (score 3):

On compiling the above code, you should get a warning like:

```
[Warning] too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

Now remove the `printf`s argument `a`.

```
 printf("%d" + 1);
```

This will print `d`.

```
100  101
%    d
^
|
Here is the starting address of the string.
```

`%d` is a string and its starting address is 100. `"%d" + 1` will give you the address `101`.

Comment: I don't see any obvious UB - just pointer arithmetic (as answered by unwind). Can you quote a standard where the UB is in this program?

Comment: Downvoter wait. I am giving you the reference.

Comment: (I haven't downvoted) - I don't think it's UB. The va_start/va_end should behave just fine for 'wrong number of arguments'. Sure - it'll be ignored but I don't see any prof that's UB. The warning is against potential error (similar to one on `if (x = y)`) I believe. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka; Passing wrong number of arguments invokes UB. But unfortunately I din't find the standard quote. But I know it there somewhere.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka; Yes. Here is the quote: `If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
behavior is undefined`-**6.5.2.2** (C11 draft).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka @haccks The cited part of the standard only applies to regular functions, not variable argument ones. I believe the relevant part of the standard is C11 7.21.6.1: `If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.` So Maciej seems to be correct, this is not undefined behavior.

Comment: Regarding the quoted part in 6.5.2.2, the function call `printf("%d" + 1, a)` corresponds well with the prototype `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`, the number of parameters are variable.

Comment: @Lundin; Then what is the format specification here for `a` ? Is it still `%d` ?

Comment: @haccks There is no valid format specifier, "the format is exhaused".  So your answer is correct except for stating that it is UB. As I understand it, printf will simply ignore superfluous parameters.

Comment: @Lundin; I removed that part. It was suspisious to me too.

Comment: @haccks: what `printf` receives for the first argument is the string `"d"`; there's no conversion specifier at all.  `a` will be evaluated as part of the call, but the value won't be used.  Excess arguments don't invoke UB.  However, the inverse - not having enough arguments for the format, such as `printf("%d");` - *will* invoke UB.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to do this?
if you want you can do like
do like

```
          printf("%d", a+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you'll understand what unwind is trying to make you understand

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int a = 5,b = 4;
    printf("%d %d" + 4, a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: d

Since it takes the 4th character inside the double quotes in printf() statement..

If number is 3

OUTPUT:  5

If number is 2

OUTPUT: 5

If number is 1

OUTPUT: d